Checking new files added in patch(msp)
We are facing some patch issue due to build pipeline where redundant files are added during patch creation. To avoid such issues, I am trying to check list of new files added in patch(msp) compared to base msi post build.
I am able to check this using Orca and Installshield tool but is there any automated way to get list of new files using Windows Installer API?
